# Peerjs audio call issue with IE

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I have implemented a user-to-user audio call system using this guide:
http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/05/03/implementing-audio-calls-with-peerjs/

It is now completed and works perfectly on my site when using Google Chrome.

However when I try to connect to a user on IE 8 I receive the error:
Your browser does not support the audio element.

In Mozilla that call initiates, but does not connect.

One of the reasons I wanted to use peerjs is because I thought it would be cross-browser (and device) compatible.

Has anyone encountered this issue and have a clue as to why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: What clue do you need more than *Your browser does not support the audio element.*? Compatibility table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

Comment: I'm trying to determine if peerjs can be implemented in a way that it will work in IE.  I know IE is crap and I don't use it, but some people still do.

Comment: Ok so IE8 does not support audio without a plugin.. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: No, IE is not crap, IE**8** is just 6 years old, try your code with a 6 years old version of Chrome/Firefox and you'll have a good laugh.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the web audio api in Mozilla is buggy as well. You should be very careful using web audio api with mozilla.

Comment: So it seems like Chrome is the only way to go.  It is my default browser, but unfortunately many users to use IE and other browsers that are not as friendly to user-to-user interactions like audio, video, etc.

Comment: @Gary not sure about web audio, but WebRTC is working just fine in Firefox for a long time, Kilian, can you explain the buggy part of web audio?

Comment: i don't know exactly. A lot of web audio api things are buggy in firefox. Try for example my site http://1ln.de nothing fancy in web audio api Mozilla says all should be supported but i get decode audio data errors. I just don't know why. I tried nights solving but then said: "F.... that FF".